# Are there canonical strong arguments for Moore's "here is an hand" argument proving that you are not me?

Tags: reality, externalism, moore

If [Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_is_one_hand) is wrong about the external world a strange situation emerge: the very skeptical people that criticise him must be *inside* Moore's mind. Actually, if the critics are right, Moore himself must be inside *my* (!) mind, because, if the external world doesn't exist,
there is no space for an external Moore. But at this point, if *everything* is in *my* mind, Stackexchange is in my mind too. Therefore if somebody can post a comment proving that he/she/it *is not me* then we validated once more Moore's argument.

**Are there canonical strong arguments for Moore's "here is an hand" argument proving that you are not me?**

Comment: How could someone prove they aren't you or a figment of your subconscious imagination, something like that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the skeptical mind is correct there is no Moore's mind but only the idea (fancy) of Moore in skeptical's mind.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I didn't get your second comment. Can you explain? thanks

Comment: Are you arguing that there is no way to prove that I am not a product of your mind, or that this is not a way to do it?

Comment: See also [this post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/51078/is-g-e-moores-here-is-one-hand-argument-a-bit-naive). In a nutshell (Wiki' Hand argument entry): "In his 1925 essay "A Defence of Common Sense", Moore argues against idealism and skepticism toward the external world on the grounds that skeptics could not give reasons to accept their metaphysical premises that were more plausible to him than the reasons he had to accept the common sense claims about our knowledge of the world that skeptics and idealists must deny."

Comment: i feel that you should be able to know that i have qualia, and am unsure why the inverse isn't true (for me about you), if not with the same certainty i have for my own experiences, then with enough not to worry

Comment: I find the question unclear. Are you asking for counter-arguments AGAINST Moore's argument, or are you looking for an additional, supporting argument that can also account for solipsism?

Comment: I'm looking for an argument to support Moore

Answer (score 0):

If you can refine a definition for what you are, then I'll do as you ask.

You observe a stream of thoughts?

Do you observe the observation of such too?

I guess you could observe both those things.

But if you are not the thoughts, then please describe what you are, as an observer of thoughts who may consider themself to have a body, a body made of cells, which die and are replaced many times throughout your life. Then we can talk again. I won't give you any hints on how to do so, because I haven't cared enough to think about it, I'm more worried about the plight of the ostrich ;)

Comment: I think I do. I am a human born in '79, I have a kid and a dog

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose extreme skepticism is true. Then all of the extreme skeptics are figments of your imagination, so why are you wasting your time arguing with them?

Comment: Because I want to challenge them. It's not nice to have a skeptic person inside your brain :) I need to proove them real